# jQuery Zoomable Vertical Bar Graph

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, charts

I have 24hours of reporting data that comes right down to the second that I need to visually display on a website. Does anyone know of any jQuery or JS libraries/plugin available that will do this and also allow zooming in and out of the data?

Check out this screen:
[image: screenshot]

Would it be possible to code this up maybe? Otherwise maybe I would need to specify the start and end date and times and then build some sort of CSS table/div that way?

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would start out looking at http://www.highcharts.com/

Highcharts looks great and can be easily modified to suit you.

Cheers!